# How to Retrieve Magento Core Variables in CMS Blocks or Pages?

Tags: magento

Changing templates isn't an option in my situation and even so if I make a full HTML page with just two integrated "product blocks: (product name, product image, product price, buy me)", it seems easier to just call the two products you need and insert them directly.

So I'm curious to know if I can retrieve Magento {{variables}}  such as product names, images, prices,... . I'm perfectly happy to use Magento Custom Variables to create functions to retrieve these, but I have no idea as to where to start. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible, nor is it sensible, to do this all from the CMS page.

You're best bet would be to [create a widget](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/introducing-magento-widgets/).  Widgets are reusable template tags that are very similar to the blocks used in the Magento layout system.

Once your widget is made, you can then call the widget in the CMS page with a product option, `{{widget type="mywidgets/productname" product_id="1"}}`, and modify the widget's output based on the product id entered.

The tutorial I've linked to is very good, and should be a great starting point.

Comment: Thanks Nick, but it seems like Magento handles this in a pretty stupid way. I can indeed use a Widget, but since I can't actually create a new kind of widget, this is too limited. Also, the way of calling a product (let's use the "product link for example"), is just ridiculous. You are calling a **product_id**, which nobody knows, I do however know it's **SKU**.

Comment: `{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_link" anchor_text="Testing: Anchor Custom Text" title="Testing: Anchor Custom Title" template="catalog/product/widget/link/link_block.phtml" id_path="product/35"}}`

Comment: @WouterB Why can't you make a new kind of widget?  You could quite easily improve that widget to use SKU, instead of product id, using `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku)`.